# php 5.3.2 with apache 2.2

Tags: windows, windows-xp, apache-2.2, php5

just installed php 5.3.2 with apache 2.2.
I am not able to restart apache because apache is not able to load the php5 module.  The dll file php5apache2_2.dll exists, the path is correct in the conf file, still it doesn't load.  My OS is windows XP 64 bit.

What am I doing wrong? :(

Answer (score 0):

Can you possible post what is the error message being display when you try to run apache or the error that is spawned inside error_log in your log files from your apache(usually inside the log folder of apache) ?

Comment: never mind, I reinstalled PHP and it worked.  Now I need to get oracle working.

I didn't do anything different, just uninstalled PHP and reinstalled it.

Comment: well even so i would still recommend you to take a look at the error_log if you fall into the same problem again and a simple reinstall does not work, that could lead you to what is going on, anyway glad you managed it out.

Comment: yes sure, will do.  Fighting with Oracle now.  I have the dll, I can connect to oracle from sql developer, but apache doesn't like oci8.dll

Comment: ha, no DLLs are loading now.  path is correct, I've added the extension to the ini file...what am I doing wrong? :(

Comment: Your first question should be closed. For your Oracle problem open another question, if you want.